# Empty DropDownList on Page Load

Tags: asp.net, wcf, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I have a `DropDownList` being populated with items coming through `DataBinding` from a `WCF` webservice. However, whenever I first start the page the first item in the list gets selected automatically, while I would like it to start completely blank. Perhaps I could easily solve this by adding a blank item on the top of the  list's items, but I don't want this blank item to show once the users clicks the `DropDownList`. Can I accomplish this in any easy way?

Comment: Do you want to remove empty item, when user select some other item ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DDL.InsertAt(0, new Item('','0'));
DDL.Attributes["onclick"] = "if(this[0].value=='0') this.remove(0);";
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I do:

```
        using (Entities db = new Entities())
        {
            ddlRelationships.DataSource = (from q in db.RelationshipTypes where (q.Active == true) orderby q.Description select q);
            ddlRelationships.DataValueField = "Code";
            ddlRelationships.DataTextField = "Description";
            ddlRelationships.DataBind();

            ddlRelationships.Items.Insert(0, "--Please Make Selection--");
            ddlRelationships.Items[0].Value = "0";
        }
```

Note, after I bind the data to the ddL, I then manual insert a new item at position '0'. You should be able to adapt to your situation pretty easily. Later in my validator I check to see if something other than the '0' has been selected if/when I want to force a selection by the user.

Comment: That's not what he is looking, he already accomplished this, but now he need to remove the item, once user select different option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ClearSelection method of the DropDownList. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.clearselection.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ddl_type.Items.Add(new ListItem("", "0"));
            ddl_type.Items.Add(new ListItem("Item 1", "1"));
            ddl_type.Items.Add(new ListItem("Item 2", "2"));
            ddl_type.Items.Add(new ListItem("Item 3", "3"));
            ddl_type.Items.Add(new ListItem("Item 4", "4"));
            ddl_type.Attributes.Add("onclick", "manageType('" + ddl_type.ClientID + "');");
}

<script type="text/javascript">
        function manageType(pType) {
            var list = document.getElementById(pType);
            if(list[0].value == '0') // the value of the removed value
                list.remove(0);
        }
    </script>
```